# How to tune XGBClassifier's each and every hyper-parameter "efficiently"?

Tags: machine-learning, python, xgboost

It's a generic question on tuning hyper-parameters for `XGBClassifier()`
I have used `gridsearch` but as my training set is around `2,00,000` it's taking huge time and heats up my laptop.

I need codes for efficiently tuning my classifier's parameters for **best** performance.

Comment: can you post your code i.e you are using for gridsearch ???

Comment: Sure.
I am using a slightly modified version of the code given here:
_http://www.codiply.com/blog/hyperparameter-grid-search-across-multiple-models-in-scikit-learn/_ I just commented other models and inserted XGBClassifier there and in parameters I wrote 
`{'n_estimators':[10,20,10,500], `
`'learning_rate':[0.3,1,10 **etc**`

Comment: look at these tutorials they explained it very well . [Tune the Number and Size](http://machinelearningmastery.com/tune-number-size-decision-trees-xgboost-python/) ,  [Tune Learning Rate](http://machinelearningmastery.com/tune-learning-rate-for-gradient-boosting-with-xgboost-in-python/) , you can also try [Multithreading Support](http://machinelearningmastery.com/best-tune-multithreading-support-xgboost-python/) for Xgboost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its kind of difficult to avoid a large processing time when you have many parameters and a large sample.

A better method than gridsearch is Bayesian Optimization, this library even has done examples for xgboost ( https://github.com/fmfn/BayesianOptimization ) 
A good trick as well is to take a reduced sample of your data set, if you have over 2 million samples, you might acquire very similar results with smaller subsets (given that they have a similar distribution).

Comment: Taking subsets is what I did for my `gridsearch`. thanks